# ASP .NET MVC Bind to multiple model properties from single element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to bind html data-* attribute to separate property in my model. How to do that?

As you can see here my button is binding to Operation property and I would like to bind data-* to property Data_RemoveAt.

```
public enum LinkListOperation
{
    AddOne,
    RemoveOne,
    RemoveAll,
    Submit,
    RemoveAt
}
public class StepThree_Notification_TemplateEmailViewModel
{
    public LinkListOperation Operation { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("data-removeat")]
    public int Data_RemoveAt { get; set; }
}
@using (var form = Html.BeginForm("AcceptTask", "Task", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>Linki:</div>
    for(int i = 0; i < Model.Links.Count; ++i)
    {
      <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(f => f.Links[i], new { Name = string.Format("Model.Links[{0}]", i) })
        <button value="RemoveAt" type="submit" name="Model.LinkOperation" data-removeat="@i">Remove</button>
    </div>
    }
    <button value="AddOne" type="submit" name="Model.LinkOperation">MORE</button>
    <button value="RemoveOne" type="submit" name="Model.LinkOperation">LESS</button>
    <button value="RemoveAll" type="submit" name="Model.LinkOperation">REMOVE ALL</button>
    <button value="Submit" type="submit" name="Model.Operation">OK</button>
}
```

Comment: Is this an AJAX request?

Comment: @johnnycreaks no, it's not. I'm trying not use ajax right now :)

Comment: What is your intention when the button is clicked?

Comment: to remove element at specific index

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using ajax, what you can do is to wrap your submit button inside a form tag and set the values you want to sent as form fields. You may use hidden fields for that.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Links.Count; ++i)
{

    <div>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(f => f.Links[i],
                                     new { Name = string.Format("Model.Links[{0}]", i) })
       @using(Html.BeginForm("Remove","Home"))
       {
        <input type="hidden" name="Operation" value="@Model.Operation" />
        <input type="hidden" name="RemoveIndex" value="@i" />

        <button value="RemoveAt" type="submit" name="Model.Operation">Remove</button>
       }
    </div>
}
```

Assuming your action method looks like this

```
public ActionResult Remove(string Operation,int RemoveIndex)
{
  // to do : return something with the passed in values.
}
```

If you already have an outer `form` tag, This approach won't be ideal as nested forms are not a good idea. You may consider using javascript-ajax code to read the data attribute value and send it to server.

You do not need to add the form tag like what i mentioned above. Keep your markup as it is except, we will add a css class to the submit button which we will use later as the jQuery selector.

```
 <button value="RemoveAt" class='removeBtn' data-removeat="@i"
                type="submit" name="Model.Operation">Remove</button>
```

And add this javscript to listen to the click event on the button and read the data attribute value and then make an ajax post call. Assuming you have jQuery library loaded to your page,

```
$(function(){

  $(".removeBtn").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     var _this=$(this);
     var removeIndex=_this.data("removeat");
     var op=_this.attr("name");
     var url = "@Url.Action("Remove","Home")";
     url=url+"?Operation="+op+"&RemoveIndex="+removeIndex;
     $.post(url,function(res){
       //do something when a response comes back, may be update the UI/reload the page ?
        //window.location.href=window.location.href;
     });      

  });

});
```

Comment: My mistake, I didn't wrote it but whole for(){...} is inside form.

Comment: Then why are you having submit button inside the loop ? Nested forms are not good idea :) Can't you use ajax ?

Comment: This approach doesn't work if he's relying on another outer form.

Comment: @Shyju I don't use nested forms, look at my updated code.

Comment: You already have an outer form tag ( which you did not include in the question initially). My first answer includes form tags inside each item in the for loop and that will be nested tag. I posted an updated answer including the ajaxified solution which does not need to you create the nested forms.

Comment: I was trying to avoid AJAX ... Is it really unavoidable here?

Comment: I think you should ajax to do this with. You can also remove the corresponding container div using some nice jQuery fadeout effect which gives a nice user experience than a complete form post.